# Controlling scrollbar from controller in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, scrollbar

I have made a list horizontally scrollable, but I want to control scrolling from a specific widget. In the diagram if I hold the bottom video progress bar and move it on right it should make the screen scroll. Also it adjusts its position when I scroll list horizontally by sliding the screen. I have all the widgets made. I just want to know how to sync them.

[image].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position` in `scroll controller`. For example - if I have to perform an operation when user reaches end of list of widgets, this is the condition -

```
if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {}
```